# Object prototype being included in array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a function that pulls the lat/lng from an MVCArray of markers. The function is below. However, each object in the mapData array contains the prototype of the native object, along with lat/lng. I have played around with hasOwnProperty, but without much luck. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

```
    function prepareMarkers() {
    var mapData = [];

    // All we need from our markers list is the coordinates of the marker and title if it has one
    markers.forEach(function(elem, index) {
        mapData.push({
            lat: elem.getPosition().lat(),
            lng: elem.getPosition().lng()
        });
    });

    return mapData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting native objects into the mapData array.  That's what this is.  It's an object.

```
    {
        lat: elem.getPosition().lat(),
        lng: elem.getPosition().lng()
    }
```

So, it's working exactly as it should.  Since they are objects, they should have the methods from the prototype of the native object.  Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve here?  Everything you've described so far sounds correct.

In your array, you can just access things like this:

```
var latitude = mapData[0].lat;
var longitude = mapData[0].lng;
```

Comment: Yep, not sure what I was worried about, thanks for the clarity.